# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Let there be a sequence define by $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$.

first we can see that $a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{a_n}\geq$ monotonically increasing

let assume there is a limit L so $L=L+\frac{1}{L}\rightarrow0=\frac{1}{L}$ so there is no limit in $\mathbb R$

I am trying to visual the sequence it is a numbers as n grows there is a smaller and smaller  fraction that is add, because we can not find and $\epsilon$ that from than on all the sequence will be in that range (if it, let say $\epsilon$=2.5111) there will be $a_n=2.5112$
Is this intuition right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming $a_0 > 0$ the sequence is monotonically increasing and has no finite limit.  In fact, asymptotically $a_n \approx \sqrt{2n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_n=a_n^2$. Notice that $b_{n+1}=a_n^2+\frac{1}{a_n^2}+2 \ge b_n+2$, hence $b_n \ge b_0+2n$ and thus $b_n$ is unbounded and $a_n$ as well.